# Dojo+Phonegap OpenStreetMaps for Android

Tags: android, cordova, dojo

I need to get OpenStreetMap running under Dojo. I followed this example : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/geo/openlayers.html
The problem is that the map is not rendered and I don't know why. The example implementation is this one : http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileOpenLayers/demo.html

When i copy the code and run it locally it does not work !

My code so far (it is the same as in the given example) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head profile="http://www.w3.org/2002/12/namespace">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <title>Dojo OpenLayers Map Demo</title>
        <!-- hosted version of Open Layer libraries -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.10/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: 1,  async:1"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body style='visibility:hidden;'>
        <div id="home" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" selected="true" >
            <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" label="OpenLayers Map"></h1>
            <h2 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory">Go To:</h2>
            <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
                <li id="paris" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="mapPage" transition="slide">
                    Paris
                </li>
                <li id="newyork" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="mapPage" transition="slide">
                    New York
                </li>
                <li id="lacolle" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="mapPage" transition="slide">
                    La Colle sur Loup
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mapPage" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
            <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" back="Back" moveTo="home" id="mapHeader"></h1>
            <div id="map" style="height:100%; width:100%; background-color: #b5d0d0;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> </html>
```

My research so far : When I use absolute values for the map-div, it works :

```
<div id="map" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color: #b5d0d0;">
                </div>
```

But I need to get it in fullscreen. How can I resolve this problem ?